# What is the maximum size a session variable can hold?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

What is the maximum size a session variable can hold ? I am trying to store object in session variable, if object size is under 80 KB, then working fine and if the size is greater than 80 KB then on retrieval I am getting an exception.

How can I increase the session variable size?

This behaviour is on my production server, on the development machine I can store big objects like above 500 KB etc..

I am implementing something like... http://aspalliance.com/1221_CodeSnip_Uploading_Multiple_Files_At_Once.all

Here is my code:

```
private static int count = 0;

protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int loopCount = 0; loopCount < count; loopCount++)
    {
        HtmlInputFile hif = (HtmlInputFile)Session["myupload" + loopCount];
        String filePath = Server.MapPath("~/AdvImages/") + loopCount.ToString() + "_" + hif.PostedFile.FileName;
        hif.PostedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
        Session.Abandon();
    }
}
protected void btnAdd_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["myupload" + count] = FileUpload1;
    count++;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Pina, Actually I am storing fileupload object and if the file size is greater than 80 KB, I am getting exception like "Cannot access a closed file"

Comment: Which session state mode are you using?  InProc?  SQL?

Comment: Can you post your code.  You said in the comments that you are doing something different if it's over 80k, so is doesn't sound like a size problem, just a problem with your code in that case.

Comment: @Sosh, Actually I am implmenting this thing http://aspalliance.com/1221_CodeSnip_Uploading_Multiple_Files_At_Once.all Multiple fileload atonce

Comment: @Sosh, I am 100% sure, that there is no problem with my code, because I have check all alternative and finally I am reach that this the problem

Comment: thanks for all  the time, I have posted my code..Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change requestLengthDiskThreshold to this:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" 
                 maxRequestLength="20000" 
                 useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
                 requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2):

From what i can think of, storing files in a session variable is a bad choice! Instead you can think of putting them into a temp location and then when upload is clicked you can put the to the real storage. Later on you can clear off the temp storage.