# Maximum size of session data in different browser

Tags: php, session, browser

I am storing data in session variable (using PHP). I don’t know what is the limit for session.
I am using Firefox version 3.6.

Wanted to know maximum size of session variable for different browsers(FF, MSIE7/8, chrome, opera, safari )

Also please suggest that, storing data in session variable is good way ? I am not storing user's confidential data in session.

Thanks for your suggestions!!!

-Pravin

Comment: What do you mean storing in "browser session"? How exactly are you storing information? Since HTTP is stateless, what mechanism are you using to preserve state? Cookies? Hidden forms? Query strings? Something else?

Comment: @Oded: m sorry for short explannation...i have updated my question. It's a session variable.

Comment: Session variable. So, you are using ASP.NET? Can you tag your question with the appropriate tags as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202900/what-can-be-the-maximum-size-for-the-session/3203759#3203759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you store something in session, this is usually left on server side and only session id is stored in browser.

If you store cookie, then it is indeed limited to few kb, and you'd better keep it as little as possible, as it's sent with EACH request - this consumes alot of bandwidth.

So keep it as tiny as possible (<100bytes).

Answer (score 0):

"length restrictions do not apply to the ASP.NET intrinsic objects like
session because they holds references. The only limitation is available memory on the machine"

Taken from this [link](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t77118-session-variable-length.html)