# ASP.NET - Using Session to store FileUpload object

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file-upload

I would like to store a `FileUpload` object which contains an image in a `Session`. Then on the next page, I would like to save the image into a folder. I am able to do that without any problem but when I try to store a larger image, the image becomes 0kb and Windows Photo Viewer says that the file is empty. Here's my code:

**Upload Form Page (C#):**

```
//FileUploadPicture is of type FileUpload
Session["fileupload_object"] = FileUploadPicture;
```

**Save Picture to Folder Page (C#):**

```
Boolean imageUploadStatus = false;
string imageExtension = System.IO.Path.
    GetExtension(((FileUpload)Session["fileupload_object"]).FileName);
string[] acceptedImageExtensions = { ".gif", ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg" };

for (int i = 0; i < acceptedImageExtensions.Length; i++)
{
    if (imageExtension.Equals(acceptedImageExtensions[i],
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            imageUploadStatus = true;
        }
}

try
{

((FileUpload)Session["fileupload_object"]).PostedFile.
    SaveAs(imagePath + ((FileUpload)Session["fileupload_object"]).FileName);

}

catch (Exception ex) { }
```

And here are the screenshots of the uploaded images.

**Small image uploaded just fine:**

[Small images uploaded without failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvjq2.jpg)

**Slightly larger image fails to be uploaded:**

[744kB image turns 0kB after uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FGVH.jpg)

So, how can I remedy this problem ? Thanks in advance.

**Updated code:**

**Upload Form Page (C#):**

```
Session["fileupload_filename"] = FileUploadPictureOfPaymentStatement.FileName;
HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile = FileUploadPictureOfPaymentStatement.PostedFile;
System.Drawing.Image image = Bitmap.FromStream(httpPostedFile.InputStream);
Session["image"] = image;
```

**Save Picture to Folder Page (C#):**

```
Boolean imageUploadStatus = false;
string imageExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension((Session["fileupload_filename"])
    .ToString());
string[] acceptedImageExtensions = { ".gif", ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg" };
for (int i = 0; i < acceptedImageExtensions.Length; i++)
{
    if (imageExtension.Equals(acceptedImageExtensions[i], 
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        imageUploadStatus = true;
    }
}

if(imageUploadStatus)
{
    try
    {
        ((System.Drawing.Image)Session["image"])
            .Save(imagePath + Session["fileupload_filename"].ToString());
    } catch(Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net)?

Comment: If you really, truly, HAVE to store this in session the don't store the actual fileUploadControl - save the file data itself.

Comment: Also, what do you do with the `imageUploadStatus`? You are not really validating to save only the accepted extensions

Comment: This is a bad idea, to store that amount of data of an image on session...

Comment: @Darren Yeah, I have changed to only storing the `FileName` and `FileBytes` into the `Session` but the problem persists.

Comment: @Felipe `imageUploadStatus` is used when checking the file extension. If the extension is not among the accepted extensions then the file won't be uploaded.

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi By the way, I tried the solution in the page that you linked to me but sadly, it does not solve the issue. Is there anything that will make Session not receiving objects above certain size ? Maybe I need to tweak that thing.

Comment: Can you edit to show your updated code?

Comment: @StevenArmstrong Session variables does not have a size limit.

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi Yeah, it seems that I have the same problem with the guy who posted the question that you linked. Thank you very much for helping me out. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Felipe Deguchi pointed out in the comments, this question is just a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755348/what-is-the-maximum-size-a-session-variable-can-hold).

I just need to add:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" 
             maxRequestLength="20000" 
             useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
             requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192"/>
</system.web>
```

at my `Web.config`.